# Shell Script Run Java Jar Service

Tags: java, shell

I want to create a shell script to run java service. The actual command is

```
java -Dorg.vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory -Dlogback.configurationFile=conf/web/logback.xml -jar vertx-web-0.1-fat.jar -conf conf/web/conf.json -cluster -cp conf/web:conf/web/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar
```

it works if I execute it just like that. But it's gonna be inaffective and messy. I decided to create a shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh

app_name=vertx-web-0.1-fat.jar

#::=== logger
logger_name=logback

#::=== config
config_base=conf/web
config_app=conf.json
config_log=logback.xml

#::=== arguments
args_factory_logger=org.vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory
args_classpath=conf/web:conf/web/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar

args_other=-cluster

#::=== execute
java -D$args_factory_logger -D$logger_name.configurationFile=$config_base/$config_log -jar $app_name -conf $config_base/$config_app $args_other -cp $args_classpath
```

But it  doesn't work and the response

```
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
Error: Unable to access jarfile vertx-web-0.1-fat.jar
: command not found
```

Can you give me any clue or solution?
Thank you

Regards,
Stefio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to delcare var in the safe way. For best practices I allways define var like this:

```
myVar="My.contet"
```

So after a little refactoring I think that the script could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

app_name="vertx-web-0.1-fat.jar"

#::=== logger
logger_name="logback"

#::=== config
config_base="conf/web"
config_app="conf.json"
config_log="logback.xml"

#::=== arguments
args_factory_logger="org.vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name=org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory"
args_classpath="conf/web:conf/web/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar"

args_other="-cluster"

#::=== execute
java -D${args_factory_logger} -D$logger_name.configurationFile=$config_base/$config_log -jar $app_name -conf $config_base/$config_app ${args_other} -cp ${args_classpath}
```

if you want to see the command executed use the echo command:

```
echo "java -D${args_factory_logger} -D$logger_name.configurationFile=$config_base/$config_log -jar $app_name -conf $config_base/$config_app ${args_other} -cp ${args_classpath}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail correction. That's absolutely works.

Comment: what is the difference between $variable and ${variable}? thank you

Comment: In my use of bash i think that using ${} is equal to "" but in my opinion i think is more readeable.

Answer (score 1):

To launch the java app as a service I recommend you take a look at [JSVC project](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html). This is really easy to implement and that takes care of many things for you.

Comment: thank you for your advice. Its really helpful for my production server deployment.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning value to your variable,  shell is treating special character as key character(not as value). thus trying to execute the special char ":".

What you need is to use quotes , either strong quote or week quote depending on your need.

In your case i suggest strong quotes.

so you command should be like :

```
 args_classpath='conf/web:conf/web/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:conf/web/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar'
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I should use quote for variable with unique character.